# How to customize and change color of a menu in ant design?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, menuitem, antd

I'm currently using reactJs along with ant design to help me build a website. However, I've stumbled upon a problem. I can change the actual color of a menu, but I can't change the color of the menu item when it's been selected, or when the mouse is hovering over it. Here's the menu, [Menu Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CQKC.png) I want to change that white to a light green, but I haven't found any way to directly access it and change it. Also, I don't want to use LESS to do it.

Does anyone know how to fix this? Here's my code for the layout.

```
import { Layout, Menu, Icon, Row, Button, Col } from 'antd';
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";


const { Header, Sider, Content } = Layout;
const { SubMenu } = Menu;

class BasicLayout extends React.Component {
  state = {
    collapsed: false,
    path: this.path
  };

  toggle = () => {
    this.setState({
      collapsed: !this.state.collapsed,
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <Layout>
        <Sider className='ant-menu' trigger={null} collapsible collapsed={this.state.collapsed}>
          <div className="logo" />
          <Menu className='ant-menu' mode="inline" defaultSelectedKeys={['1']}>
            <Menu.Item key="1" >
              <Link to='/'>
                <Icon type="home" />
                <span>Home</span>
              </Link>
            </Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key="2">
              <Link to='/about'>
                <Icon type="plus" />
                <span>About</span>
              </Link>
            </Menu.Item>
            <SubMenu key="3" title={<span><Icon type="database" /><span>Directory</span></span>}>
                <Menu.Item>
                  <Link to='/resources/living'>
                    <span>Living Resources</span>
                  </Link>
                </Menu.Item>
                <Menu.Item>
                  <Link to='/water2'>
                    <span>Non-Living Resources</span>
                  </Link>
                </Menu.Item>
                <Menu.Item>
                  <Link to='/resources/recycle'>
                    <span>Recycling Resources</span>
                  </Link>
                </Menu.Item>

                <Menu.Item>
                  <Link to='/resources/reducing'>
                    <span>Reducing Resources</span>
                  </Link>
                </Menu.Item>
                <Menu.Item>
                  <Link to='/resources'>
                    <span>General</span>
                  </Link>
                </Menu.Item>
            </SubMenu>
          </Menu>
        </Sider>
        <Layout>
          <Header style={{ background: '#fff', padding: 0 }}>
            <Icon
              className="trigger"
              type={this.state.collapsed ? 'menu-unfold' : 'menu-fold'}
              onClick={this.toggle}
            />
          </Header>
          <Content
            style={{
              margin: '24px 16px',
              padding: 24,
              background: '#fff',
              minHeight: 280,
            }}
          >
            {this.props.children}
          </Content>
        </Layout>
      </Layout>
    );
  }
}
export default BasicLayout;
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to change Link to **NavLink** and add attribute **activeClassName**

```
<NavLink  to="/portoflio" activeClassName="your-active-class" className="link">Portoflio</NavLink>
```

For the hover options you can achieve it only with css

```
a.link:hover {
  /*Any style you want to have link on mouse over*/
  background-color: yellow;
}
.your-active-class{
 /*Any style you want to have link that is active*/
 background-color: yellow;
 }
```

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

Comment: How can I do that with css? Sorry, but I'm new at this

Comment: I update my answer please let me know if that works for you